# Map containing the powers of 2

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am creating a method that generates a map with the first 20 powers of 2. 
A map with as key the exponent and as value the result.

I am using the functional features of JAVA8 to achieve this.
Currently I got it done, but the it takes me two lines.

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> generatePowerMap(int base){
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,20)
            .map(n -> ((Double) Math.pow(base, n)).intValue())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 20)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(n-> n, list::get));
}
```

I am wondering how it can be done in a oneliner but cannot figure it out.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You obtain the value by fetching it from a list. Don't. Compute it instead, as you're doing in your first stream: `n -> ((Double) Math.pow(base, n)).intValue()`

Comment: You are right. I should have thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet You are telling me to not do that because I can write it shorter or because it is bad practice? I know to avoid side effects but since I am not modifying that list it is not a side effect, isn't?

Comment: I'm telling you not to do that because there is no reason to put all values in a list just to get them back in a second iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value is just the exponent operation, yes?

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 20)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(n-> n, n -> ((Double) Math.pow(base, n)).intValue()));
```

Comment: Still, casting a `double` to `Double`, to call `intValue()` on it, is a wasteful obfuscation of just casting the `double` to `int`, which still happens behind the scenes. It's much cleaner to honestly cast: `n -> (int)Math.pow(base, n)`. Though, when the `base` is known to be two, as the question's title suggests, you can just use `n -> 1<<n`.